# Writing array to single row

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created an API which iterates through JSON format data, reading 2 items per ID. I'm storing this data in an array called values[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In order to put the values of `values` to one row, please modify `values.push([timestamp, price]);` to `values.push(timestamp, price);`. By this, each value is put in `values` which is one dimensional array.
- In order to put `values` from the row 3, in this modification, it checks whether the row 3 for putting values is empty.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
    values.push([timestamp, price]);
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("rawStockData");
  ss.getRange("A3:BH3").setValues(values);
}
```

To:

```
    values.push(timestamp, price);  // Modified
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("rawStockData");
  var range = ss.getRange(3, 1, 1, values.length);  // Modified
  if (range.isBlank()) {  // Added
    range.setValues([values]);
  } else {
    ss.appendRow(values);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: Thanks again Tanaike. Do you have a link i can follow up on with more details on your explanation?

Comment: @user13599639 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I have already been added the links for `push()` and `appendRow(rowContents)`. For example, when you want to know about `isBlank()`, you can confirm [it from the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank). If you want to check other methods for Spreadsheet service, you can check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

Comment: @user13599639 If you want to know about other useful links, you can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: @user13599639 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.